# Make activity match current system dialog?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-theme

I'd like to be able to create an Activity that matches a default system Dialog. So in Android 2.2, it'll look like a Dialog for that version, in 2.3 it'll look like a Dialog for 2.3, etc.

The usual answer starts off with set `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"` in the Activity manifest. However, that just gives you a floating box with *unstyled* text. What's missing is a title over a title bar, the dialog text, and the dialog buttons---all styled to match a system Dialog. What system styles should I use?

For example, I found `TextAppearance_DialogWindowTitle` in R.style. This gives you the text size for the title. Still missing is styling the title background, the buttons, etc.. Any ideas? Android style and theme documentation is sorely lacking.

I would just use the dialog builder except that I need to use a custom icon, so I would be back to square one styling a custom dialog....